# org.apache.lucene.index.IndexNotFoundException: no segments* file found in org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory

Tags: java, netbeans, lucene

I am new to Java and Lucene. My code gets a line from a file and stores it in Lucene Index. But when I create an `IndexReader` to search and read from the index it throws an exception.

My java code is below. On creating the `IndexReader` it throws an `IndexNotFoundException`

```
static String itemsfreq[];
static StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_35);
static IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_35, analyzer);

public static void index_data(Directory indexed_document,int doc_num,IndexWriter w) throws IOException
    {
    for(int i = 0;i < itemsfreq.length;i++)
        {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new Field(Integer.toString(doc_num)+","+itemsfreq[i],itemsfreq[i++], Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
        w.addDocument(doc);
        }
    }
//Gets string from a file and insert it in INDEX named indexed_document
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fullText100.txt"));
    String line;
    int i = 0;
    Directory indexed_document = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(indexed_document, config);
    while((line=reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
        if(i == 1)
            {
            break;
            }
        itemsfreq = line.split(" ");
        index_data(indexed_document,i,writer);
        i++;
        }

    IndexReader r = IndexReader.open(indexed_document);
    }
```

Answer (score 34):

before open the index by using a reader, call once `writer.commit()`

Comment: I was facing similar issue, and using `writer.commit()` fixed it. If I had used `writer.close()`, I would have to re-open the writer again. Your suggestion is better than the previous one.

Comment: Indeed, this is the right solution as it is recommended by Lucene docs to re-use single instances of IndexWriter and IndexReader; This way I'm not forced to closw writer and create it again when needed.

Answer (score 19):

In order to write the changes to the Index you have to close the index writer and then open the IndexReader.

```
writer.close();
```

If you have to open the IndexReader before writing is completed, you have to tell the IndexReader to reopen the index in order to see the changes.

Answer (score 10):

You need to do is to explicitly call commit before opening your IndexSearcher.

```
    directory = new RAMDirectory();
    iwriter = new IndexWriter(directory, config);
    iwriter.commit();
```

Now Open Searcher

```
ireader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
isearcher = new IndexSearcher(ireader);
```

Also remember you need to call commit after adding documents otherwise search may not find it. Searcher needs to reopened after commit (of course  close old searcher).

```
iwriter.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error (in Lucene.Net, C#) because I had created an index by creating the appropriate directory on my filesystem and `FSDirectory` in memory, but hadn't actually added any documents yet.

Specifically, the code to add new documents was checking to make sure that it wasn't adding a duplicate with a reader, but the exception was thrown when trying to add the first document, because there were no segments yet.

I dealt with this like so:

```
// Make a reader to check the index for duplicates
// The reader will only be aware of items that were in the index before it was created
IndexReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = IndexReader.Open( index, true );
} catch( IOException ) {
    // There is no segments file because the index is empty
    reader = null;
}

... // inside a method called by that scope, with reader passed in

// See if it exists already
// If the reader is null, then the index is empty
if( reader != null ) {
    var existsTerm = new Term( SingleFieldIndexManager.FieldName, formattedTerm );
    var matches = reader.TermDocs( existsTerm );
    if( matches.Next() ) {
        // It's already in there, no need to add again
        return;
    }
}

... // back to the first method after a return

// dispose of the reader if we managed to create one
if( reader != null ) {
    reader.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Hey, I am having the same problem as you. But I don't understand how you solved it. If there are no files then it enters the catch block and that's it, right?

Comment: Found the problem. I got this error on creating the IndexWriter with parameter create = false

Comment: Lucent.NET 4.8 (I'm using version 4.8.0-beta00006) uses class `IndexWriterConfig` instead which in turn has a property `OpenMode` which also allows specifying something like `CREATE` or `CREATE_OR_APPEND`. My expectation was that it'd create the index for me, but it appears to ignore that parameter. It's very well possible that I'm not using it correctly just yet. I used 3.0.3 previously, which was able to handle the case when an index was empty.